# How to compile a Linux LTO-enabled library with Premake 5?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, premake, lto

SO wisdom, I'm turning to you. I'm trying to build a 64-bit static lib using LTO with Makefiles and Premake 5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Here's the premake script i'm using:

```
-- premake5.lua
workspace "TestApp"

    location "TestApp" -- The directory of generated files - .sln, etc.
    configurations { "Debug", "Shipping" }
    platforms { "Linux_Static", "Linux_DLL" }
    targetdir "TestApp/Build/%{cfg.platform}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
    objdir "TestApp/Build/"
    language "C++"

    architecture "x86_64"
    system "linux"

    filter "platforms:*Static"
        kind "StaticLib"

    filter "platforms:*DLL"
        kind "SharedLib"

    filter "kind:SharedLib"
        defines { "TEST_USE_DLL", "TEST_DLL_EXPORT" }

    -- Configuration filters
    configuration "*"
        flags { "ExtraWarnings", "C++14", "MultiProcessorCompile", "ShadowedVariables", "UndefinedIdentifiers" }

    configuration { "Debug" }
        symbols "On"
        defines { "TEST_DEBUG" }
        optimize "Debug"

    configuration "Shipping"
        defines { "TEST_SHIPPING" }
        optimize "Full"
        flags { "LinkTimeOptimization" }
        -- step 1
        --buildoptions "--plugin=$$(gcc --print-file-name=liblto_plugin.so)"

        -- step 2
        --toolset "clang"

        -- step 3
        --premake.tools.gcc.ar = "gcc-ar"

-- Projects
project "TestCore"
    location "TestApp/Core"
    files { "TestApp/Core/*.h", "TestApp/Core/*.cpp" }
    includedirs { "TestApp/" }


project "UnitTests"
    location "TestApp/Tests"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    links { "TestCore" }
    objdir "TestApp/Tests/Build/"

    files { "TestApp/Tests/UnitTests/*.cpp", "TestApp/ThirdParty/Catch/*" }
    includedirs { "TestApp/ThirdParty/Catch", "TestApp/" }

    removedefines { "TEST_DLL_EXPORT" }

    filter { "platforms:*DLL", "system:linux" }
    runpathdirs { "Build/%{cfg.platform}/%{cfg.buildcfg}" }
```

"Shipping" is the faulty configuration. I also [bundled the whole test project in a zip](http://scylardor.fr/files/testBreaking2.zip) for you to try to reproduce the issue.

The errors I have when compiling the TestCore library are first `plugin needed to handle lto object`, then `plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so is not licensed under a GPL-compatible license`.

What can we do about it ? If you have any knowledge to make it work with GCC, please help.

what you would do to reproduce the GCC errors after extracting the zip:

1. cd testBreaking
2. premake5 gmake
3. cd TestApp
4. make config=shipping_linux_static TestCore (get the "plugin needed to handle lto object" error)
5. Uncomment line 37 of premake5.lua to get the "not licensed under a GPL-compatible license" error
6. Uncomment line 43 to use gcc-ar instead of ar, notice it doesn't work either
7. Using gcc option -fuse-linker-plugin doesn't help

Some more system info:

- ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- gcc 5.4, make 4.1, ar 2.26.1
- premake 5.0.0-alpha11

---

I got it working with Clang. Using `toolset clang` for Shipping configuration (using LLVM 3.9), the library seems to compile fine. *But* I got another error:

`error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one`

I managed to work around this issue by calling `ranlib Build/Linux_Static/Shipping/libTestCore.a --plugin /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/lib/LLVMgold.so`, then make again.

So it painfully works using Clang.

I read that I could [create a specific premake toolset for this kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504627/adjusting-g-location-with-premake), because it's recommended replacing all gnu utils with their `gcc-` counterparts (e.g. `gcc-ar` instead of `ar`), but having rapidly tinkered with `premake.tools.gcc.ar = "gcc-ar"` with no result, I'm not so sure it would help.

Comment: Your question is very chatty and it seems like you put the important details as links.   Please invert this - put the chat somewhere else and put the details in the question.  That will help you get people to look at what is the actual problem instead of just seeing a wall of text that reads more like a short story than a technical question.

Comment: You're right, I show what I've tried that didn't work but that's a lot of text. I edited to try and keep it as short as possible, and included the whole premake script in the question.